# How to detect number of xml nodes?

Tags: java, python, xml, lxml

What is the best way to detect the number of xml nodes in a document? Here are a few examples:

```
<Items>
    <Timestamp></Timestamp>
    <Item>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <ID>4</ID>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        ...
    </Item>
</Items>
```

The above example has two xml elements (2 `Item`s), but that couldn't be detected, for example, by counting the number of occurrences of the first element after the root (`Timestamp`).

Here is a more conventional example that could:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        ...
    </Item>
    <Item>
        ...
    </Item>
</Items>
```

Or, a more ambiguous example that probably just has one element (the parent element "Items") --

```
<Items>
    <References>
        ...
    </References>
    <Talk>
        ...
    </Talk>
</Items>
```

Without knowing the structure beforehand, what would be the best way to determine the number of xml nodes in a document? The language doesn't matter here, but would prefer java or python.

Comment: May not be error-proof, but read through the file and count each instance of "</".

Comment: @Krythic please see updated question which, I think, not work too well with that approach

Comment: Write a custom parser(reading function that counts the desired nodes and ignores the others)

Comment: This seems under-specified. You say that the first example has "two xml elements", but it has three elements below the root element. So you don't count the timestamp element... but how is your program supposed to know to do that? Is it supposed to be generic? What if the XML file isn't a sequence of the same node?

Comment: How are you defining `nodes`?  For example in the last case, why just one 'node'?  Why not 3 (plus anything obscured by the ...).

Comment: @hpaulj it would be the number of repeated primary sub-elements of the root node. I know this is a somewhat ambiguous definition, but that's where I'm starting from.

Comment: Even though this question is confusing (clearly, something more specific than just “the number of XML nodes in a document” is desired), I expect the solution will be [XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html).

Comment: In Python there several xml parsers/packages. Any should let you step through the structure counting elements, nodes, etc. You may have to do things recursively. `ElementTree` is the newest one in the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"the number of repeated primary sub-elements of the root node."* While the description is open to interpretation, from the way I read it, you can read the XML into ElementTree, enumerate the root nodes by iteration and count them with `collections.Counter`.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import collections

refdoc = """<Items>
    <Timestamp></Timestamp>
    <Item>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <ID>4</ID>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        ...
    </Item>
</Items>"""

doc = ET.XML(refdoc)
counts = collections.Counter(elem.tag for elem in doc)
print(counts)
total = sum(count for count in counts.values() if count > 1)
print(total)
```

This results in

```
Counter({'Item': 2, 'Timestamp': 1})
2
```

You can even squeeze it into fewer lines

```
total = sum(count for count in collections.Counter(
    elem.tag for elem in ET.XML(refdoc)).values() 
    if count > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

"In the DOM, everything in an XML document is a node."

In XML Node and Element are different things, you seem to use them interchangeably.

From your examples, it looks like you are looking for <Item> tags (except if none are found, then <Items> counts as one), and not nodes. So simply count those?

To count the number of <Item> tags in Python, load your XML in a string called xml, fx:

```
xml = '<Items><Item>...</Item><Item>...</Item></Items>'
xml.count('<Item>')
```

Answer (score 1):

i would highly recommend to use the right tool for the task, which in this case would be XPath. using XPath, counting **element nodes** (if this is what you mean by "nodes") is as easy as:

```
count(//*)
```

counting other nodes as well (attributes, for example) is similarly easy to do.